Upgrade Vertica From Version 9.0.x to 23.4.x?
I need help understanding the steps and approach to upgrading the Vertica database from version 9.0.x to 23.4.x. I have read many discussions in the forum on this topic. But my concern was whether there was any upgrade path I should follow like first upgrading from version 9.0 to 9.1 to 9.2 to 10.0 and then to version 23.4 or jumping directly to version 23.4. Please let me know what steps I should perform to upgrade the Vertica database smoothly.

Here's what Vertica says officially for versions 9.0 to 10.1:
https://www.vertica.com/docs/11.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/InstallationGuide/Upgrade/UpgradePaths.htm:
Upgrades are generally incremental: you must upgrade to each intermediate major and minor release. For example, you upgrade from Vertica 9.0 to 10.1 in the following steps:

Vertica 9.0 to 9.1
Vertica 9.1 to 9.2
Vertica 9.2 to 9.3
Vertica 9.3 to 10.0
Vertica 10.0 to 10.1

From then on, it should be major version to next major version, and it should be:

11.0
12.0
23.3
23.4

